# pandas - combine two pandas dataframes with list columns, but combine the lists from the most recent timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

Let's say I have dataframes A and B with index `time` and a list column `food`. Both dataframes resemble history logs, the fruits and vegetables I have at the time:

A:

```
            food
time
2021-08-20  ["apple","orange"] 
2021-08-28  ["apple","orange","banana"]
```

B:

```
            food
time
2021-08-19  ["squash"] 
2021-08-24  ["squash","carrot"] 
2021-08-29  ["carrot"]
```

How can I combine the two dataframes so that it keeps tracks of both the fruits and vegetables at the time?

```
            food
time
2021-08-19  ["squash"]
2021-08-20  ["apple","orange","squash"] 
2021-08-24  ["apple","orange","squash","carrot"]
2021-08-28  ["apple","orange","banana","squash","carrot"]
2021-08-29  ["apple","orange","banana","carrot"]
```

Essentially, I want to combine the rows, and for each row, combine the foods of the two most recent entries before that timestamp. It's guaranteed that the food items in A and B don't overlap, and the timestamps between A and B don't overlap.

I tried to use pd.concat([A,B]) directly, but it doesn't combine the food items.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
# Create the first data frame
df_a = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2021-08-20', '2021-08-28'],
    'foods': [['apple', 'orange'], ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']]
})

# Create the second data frame
df_b = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2021-08-19', '2021-08-20', '2021-08-29'],
    'foods': [['squash'], ['squash', 'carrot'], ['carrot']]
})

# Merge the two data frames on the date column
merged = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on='date', how='outer')

# Concatenate the food item lists
def concat_foods(row):
    foods_x = row['foods_x'] if isinstance(row['foods_x'], list) else []
    foods_y = row['foods_y'] if isinstance(row['foods_y'], list) else []
    return list(set(foods_x + foods_y))

merged['foods'] = merged.apply(concat_foods, axis=1)

# Remove the original food item columns
merged = merged.drop(['foods_x', 'foods_y'], axis=1)

# Sort the data frame by date
merged = merged.sort_values('date')
```

Comment: this gives me the same result as pd.concat([A,B])

Answer (score 0):

One option using [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

A.index = pd.to_datetime(A.index)
B.index = pd.to_datetime(B.index)

out = pd.concat([A, B]).sort_index()

N = 2
out['food'] = [list(dict.fromkeys([e for x in l for e in x]))
               for l in swv(pd.concat([pd.Series([[]]*(N-1)), out['food']]), N)]
```

Output:

```
                                               food
time                                               
2021-08-19                                 [squash]
2021-08-20                  [squash, apple, orange]
2021-08-24          [apple, orange, squash, carrot]
2021-08-28  [squash, carrot, apple, orange, banana]
2021-08-29          [apple, orange, banana, carrot]
```

Comment: does this still work if the two dataframes don't have alternating times?

Comment: Yes, it's independent of the original order and of the origin of the rows. If you started with a single DataFrame this would be the same. But you can suggest/clarify a different logic if needed.